# dell alienware window10 and install ubuntu alongside

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot

is anyone had issue with install ubuntu alongside window 10 dell alienware?

 so far i'm trying to install the ubuntu alongside window10 but so many issues coming up....

1. ubuntu 14.10 this after I press install ubuntu black screen coming up
2. ubuntu 16   installed fined but it does not turn on after I reboot.

is dell alienware not compatible with ubuntu? .....

## or is there other setup should I remember for the setup?

is anyone had issue with install ubuntu alongside window 10 dell alienware?

 so far i'm trying to install the ubuntu alongside window10 but so many issues coming up....

1. ubuntu 14.10 this after I press install ubuntu black screen coming up
2. ubuntu 16   installed fined but it does not turn on after I reboot.

is dell alienware not compatible with ubuntu? .....
or is there other setup should I remember for the setup?

Comment: There *is* another setup you should remember: `nomodeset`. But before that install at the very minimum 16.04.3 or the current 17.04. Alienware, like most gaming PCs with high-end Nvidia graphics require Nvidia proprietary drivers and some may not be correctly supported by the default drivers included. That's why we need to use `nomodeset` (and boot and install in UEFI mode)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162076#162076  Scroll down to find instructions for UEFI.

Comment: And this other answer is a much more simplified version: https://askubuntu.com/a/111298/692175